# PHP paging, viewing a certain page first

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my script for the paging on my site when the user clicks on a league.
The league is then echoed to the screen, and if the league is over 3 rows then it splits it up in to several pages.
What I am doing after is depending on where the user is in the league (the SQL query is using `ORDER BY` the total points column in the table), e.g if the user is on page one of the league table then for it to display that page first, but if the user is on page 3 of the league table then for that page to displayed first.

Does anyone know a way in order for me to achieve this?

```
//Recently updated from answer

$sql="SELECT members.username, members.total_points FROM members, members_leagues WHERE members.username = members_leagues.username AND 
        members_leagues.sub_league = '$chosenleague' ORDER BY members.total_points DESC";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;
$found = false;
$team_position = 0;

while (!$found && $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   if ($row[username] == $_SESSION[username]) {
   $team_position = $i;
   $found = true;
   }
 $i++;
}

$rowsPerPage = 3;

$pageNum =  ceil($i/$rowsPerPage);
//end of recently updated

if(isset($_GET['page']))
    $pageNum = $_GET['page'];

$offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;
$counter = $offset + 1;

$query = " SELECT members.username, members.teamname, members.total_points, FROM members, members_leagues WHERE members.username = members_leagues.username AND members_leagues.sub_league = '$chosenleague' ORDER BY members.total_points DESC " . " LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

echo "<h3 style=\"color:red;\">$chosenleague</h3>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Position</th>";
echo "<th>Team</th>";
echo "<th>Points/Overall</th>";
echo "<th>Points/Last Race</th>";
echo "<th>Team Setup</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[username] == $_SESSION[username])
        echo "<tr style=\"color:red;\"><td>";
    else
        echo "<tr><td>";

    echo $counter;
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row[teamname];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row[total_points];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    $counter++;
}
echo "</table>";

$query   = "SELECT COUNT(members.username) AS numrows FROM members, members_leagues WHERE members.username = members_leagues.username 
AND members_leagues.sub_league = '$chosenleague'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$numrows = $row['numrows'];

$maxPage = ceil($numrows/$rowsPerPage);

$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$nav  = '';

if ($pageNum > 1)
{
    $page  = $pageNum - 1;

    $prev  = " <a href=\"$self?league=". rawurlencode($chosenleague) . "&page=". rawurlencode($page) . "\"><< Prev</a> ";
    $first = " <a href=\"$self?league=". rawurlencode($chosenleague) . "&page=". rawurlencode(1) . "\">First</a> ";
}
else
{
    $prev  = ''; 
    $first = ''; 
}

if ($pageNum < $maxPage)
{
    $page = $pageNum + 1;
    $next = " <a href=\"$self?league=". rawurlencode($chosenleague) . "&page=". rawurlencode($page) . "\">Next >></a> ";
    $last = " <a href=\"$self?league=". rawurlencode($chosenleague) . "&page=". rawurlencode($maxPage) . "\">Last</a> ";
}
else
{
    $next = '';
    $last = ''; 
}

echo "<div id=\"pagenum\">Page $pageNum of $maxPage &nbsp;". $first . $last . $prev . $next ."</div>";
```

Comment: So, you want to reorder your pagination numbers? (Page1, Page2, Page3?)

Comment: I don't want to reorder the page numbers as such, but just for the first time that the league is viewed it displays the page where the user is. So i click on the league it displays the league and the page where my team is, if the league has 30 pages and I am on the 6th page then it displays the 6th page first.

Comment: I have updated the code with the PHP part of the answer from Feida, it does not seem to be incrementing $i, its like it starts the while loop and exits straight away?. Is there anything you can see that is wrong with it? I have updated the code in my question at the top.

Comment: and by the way the team is 3rd in the table when it retrieves the results so the $i should have the value of 3?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via mysql or php:

With PHP:

Found the position of the requested record in the array, then calculate the page you have to extract and execute the corresponding query. Something like.

```
$i = 0;
$found = false;
$team_position = 0;

while (!$found && $row = mysql_fetch_row) {
  if ($row['team'] == 'team_your_searching_for') {
    $team_position = $i;
    $found = true;
  }
  $i++;
}

//calculate $top and $bottom
...

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members LIMIT $top, $bottom;";
...
```

With MySQL:

You can create a query that generates an autoincrement value and another that selects from the other's result. I mean

```
-- get the the selected member's position
SELECT team, pos FROM (SELECT team, points, @position = @position + 1 AS pos FROM members ORDER BY points) WHERE team = @the_team_your_searching_for;

-- get the nr of members
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members;

...

-- calculate the page you wanna extract (@top, @bottom), and extract it
SELECT * FROM members LIMIT @top, @bottom;
```

Comment: Hey I am having a little trouble with the PHP part you sent me, it does not seem to be incrementing $i, its like it starts the while loop and exits straight away?. Is there anything you can see that is wrong with it? I have updated the code in my question at the top.

Comment: try this -->  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); while (!$found && $row){
   if ($row[username] == $_SESSION[username]) {
   $team_position = $i;
   $found = true;
   }
 $i++;  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)
}

Comment: it is not going inside the loop due to this condition --> $row = mysql_fetch_row($result). Store $row first and then check if $row.  http://es.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: I have it working now, thanks, by the way the mysql_fetch_row returns an integer for the specified row, so instead of $row[username] it has to be $row[0], I found mysql_fetch_array worked as well for the $row[username] way. Thanks again.